# how to get id through session

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

This is my code for insert data in order colunm but my confusion is that what type of value i provide in users_id which is foriegn key in order table i want that users_id give value through session of currently logged user which want to place order and its id is save aginst his order record code is here.

```
  <% request.getSession().getAttribute("users_id");%>
  <%  String add = request.getParameter("add");
      String type = request.getParameter("order_type");
      String city = request.getParameter("city");
      String veh = request.getParameter("vehicles");
      String date = request.getParameter("order_date");
      String users_id = request.getParameter("users_id");
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection con =  
          DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/auto_lube","root", "mehar");
     Statement st = con.createStatement();
    System.out.println(add);
    //ResultSet rs;
         int i = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `user_order` (`id`, `address`, `order_type`, `city`, `vehicle`, `order_date`, `users_id`) VALUES (NULL, '"+add+"', '"+type+"', '"+city+"', '"+veh+"', '2','"+users_id+"')");
    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that try to avoid code on JSP or any design pages you use. Because due to any problem page crashed then your code will be shown on page. So use backend tool like servlet but that is quite old but for shake of learning you can use it. If possible then use hibernate, it provide very great support.

and pass your data to java code then access data of session.
if possible then pass order detail using JSON, that will be quite helpful while storing data and access it and change it any place.

Suppose you want to edit quantity of ordered item or etc, then json will be useful, each time you never have to send request to server.

Use prepared statement for to enter data in DB.
and make table `order` that have only order detail like user id (get from session) and order number.
and other table `ordermaster` that have order number and item ordered and it's quantity and price and ordered time and other details you want. so here order id of `ordermaster` will be foreign key in `order` table.